# The relation between the largest eigenvalue of $f's$ Hessian matrix and Lipschitz constant of the gradient of $f$

Tags: lipschitz-functions, hessian-matrix

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is twice continuously differentiable, and the gradient of $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
    \|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|_2\le L\|x-y\|_2, \forall\,x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n,
\end{align*}
where $L>0$ is the Lipschitz constant. Please find the relation between $L$ and the largest eigenvalue of $\nabla^2 f(x)$.

Comment: Hello @Isaac Crunch, welcome to MSE. Can you add in your question (not in the comments) what you have tried yourself and where exactly you got stuck? Questions in which you do not show your attempts or that look like 'this is my homework, make it for me', are not always well received on MSE.

Comment: I tried to show that L is an upper bound, but I haven't managed to.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder.